# How to test a single exception when method in question has multiple expected exceptions

Tags: java, junit, mockito, jaxb, junit4

I have a method that accepts a file path and does some processing on that file. But if the path is incorrect, I want to throw FileNotFoundException and create a test out of it.

Since my method in its catch throws another exception called `FileParsingException`, I have to add that in throws or try catch surrounding the test method.

And if I want to create a test for `FileNotFoundException`, it doesn't let me and error out with assertion error as `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException`. I cannot remove `FileParsingException` so how can I add `FileNotFoundException` test or for that matter what can be

Here is my how my method looks like:

```
public <T> Object getSAXSource(File xmlFile, Class<T> clazz) throws FileParsingException {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
            Unmarshaller um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            // Disable XXE
            XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
            xmlReader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
            xmlReader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
            xmlReader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
            xmlReader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);

            // Read the contents
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(is);
            Source xmlSource = new SAXSource(xmlReader, inputSource);
            return  um.unmarshal(xmlSource);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | SAXException | JAXBException e) {
            LOGGER.error("XmlParsingUtil:getSAXSource():: Error on while parsing::" + e.getMessage());
            throw new FileParsingException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } 
    }
```

And here is how I am trying to create a JUNIT

```
    //@Test(expected = FileParsingException.class)
    @Test(expected = FileNotFoundException.class)
    public void testGetSAXSourceFileNotFound() {
        
        File file = new File(resourcePath + "/Invalid.xml");

        try {
            util.getSAXSource(file, MyXMLClass.class);
            Assert.fail("Exception was expected");
        } catch (FileParsingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can someone guide me on how to create junits for the catch block. At this point any exception being tested will work as the coverage shows that catch blocks are not covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are thinking too complicated (or I misunderstood what you try to do).

Since you expect your `getSAXSource` method to throw a `FileParsingException`,
you annotate the test method with `@Test(expected = FileParsingException.class)`.
And to make the compiler happy, you need to declare the method
with `throws FileParsingException`.
You don't need the try/catch and the `Assert.fail("Exception was expected")`
because JUnit will do all that for you.
(I.e. the test will fail, when no `FileParsingException` is thrown.
It will also fail when any other exception is thrown.)

So you end up with a very simple test method:

```
@Test(expected = FileParsingException.class)
public void testGetSAXSourceFileNotFound() throws FileParsingException {
    
    File file = new File(resourcePath + "/Invalid.xml");

    util.getSAXSource(file, MyXMLClass.class);
}
```

May be you need 3 different test-cases, to test all 3 kinds
of exceptions (`FileNotFoundException`, `SAXException`, `JAXBException`)
handled inside your `getSAXSource` method,
and verify that all of them result in a `FileParsingException`.

Comment: Fritsh: How to create 3 different test cases here to handle those other exceptions? Could you please give me an example for one of them where they all result in `FileParsingException`?